# AES decryption returning incorrect result

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt Password , encrypt Password is work Fine
but decrypt Password returned wrong result.....

example:

password input : P@ssword

Password Encrypt : V????0B??y+?Em

Password Decrypt : �/T:/�b,<AI�)6   ... Here it should appear\ P@ssword

I get class from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=netcore-3.1

my Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Solution_Report
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        byte[] IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("9316FF86D31244AC");
        byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("28FDDEF86DA4244ACCC0A4FE3B316F26");
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }                  
        private void btn_Encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte [] Encrypted_Pass_byte = AesExample.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(txt_Password.Text, Key , IV);
            txt_Password_Encrypted.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encrypted_Pass_byte);
        }
        private void btn_decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] Encrypted_Password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt_Password_Encrypted.Text);
            txt_Password_Decrpted.Text = AesExample.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Encrypted_Password, Key, IV);
        }
    }
}
```

AesManaged Class

```
class AesExample
    {
        public static void en()
        {
            string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

            // Create a new instance of the Aes
            // class.  This generates a new key and initialization
            // vector (IV).
            using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
            {

                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
                Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter swEncrypt = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

       public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }
```

Comment: Passwords are *never* encrypted, they are always hashed - after salting, with a strong cryptographic algorithm, for a large number of iterations (10K in ASP.NET Identity) to ensure brute forcing them would be prohibitively expensive. By definition encryption allows *de*cryption

Comment: As for what's going wrong, you're treating 8-bit bytes as 7-bit ASCII text. At least half the bytes will be mangled, with any byte value above 127 replaced by a `?`. When you encrypt something you get back a *byte array* that contains every possible value, not just 7-bit letters. This includes values that aren't printable like `0x00`. That's why binary values are converted to Base64 if they need to be transferred as text. Use [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netcore-3.1) if you want to display the encrypted data

Comment: For production, just don't use this code. For testing, use `Encoding.UTF8` to convert user input to bytes, not `ASCII`. To display the encrypted bytes, use `txtEncrypted.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);`. To decrypt use `var bytes=Convert.FromBase64String(txtEncrypted.Text);`

Comment: It seems suspicious that you use BinaryWriter and StreamReader. I would have expected BinaryWriter/Reader or StreamWriter/Reader.

Comment: PanagiotisKanavos ... it is working thank  u pro

Comment: @JonasH i do that .. thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

display the encrypted bytes

```
        private void btn_Encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte [] Encrypted_Pass_byte = AesExample.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(txt_Password.Text, Key , IV);
            txt_Password_Encrypted.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypted_Pass_byte);
        }
```

display the decrypted String

```
        private void btn_decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Encrypted_Password = Convert.FromBase64String(txt_Password_Encrypted.Text);
            txt_Password_Decrpted.Text = AesExample.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Encrypted_Password, Key, IV);
        }
```

and using StreamWriter/Reader in Encrypting And Decrypting

Thanks for who helped me ..